# Cannot add new tiles fragment [Tiles 2, Spring, Thymeleaf]

Tags: xml, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf, tiles

I have been using Tiles 2, Thymeleaf, and Spring MVC in my application. Today I went to go add a new fragment, and it doesn't seem to register. I still get the old template. The template resolver just seems to disregard the new fragment. I've tried cleaning my project, but it didn't change anything. Does anyone know why I cannot add this new tiles fragment?

**spring-thymeleaf-tiles.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <!-- thymeleaf view resolvers with tiles integration -->
    <bean id="tilesConfigurer"
        class="org.thymeleaf.extras.tiles2.spring4.web.configurer.ThymeleafTilesConfigurer">
        <property name="definitions">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/tiles/tiles.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- template resolver -->
    <bean id="templateResolver"
        class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.templateresolver.SpringResourceTemplateResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/tiles/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
        <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" />
        <property name="characterEncoding" value="utf-8" />
        <property name="cacheable" value="false" />
    </bean>

    <!-- template engine -->
    <bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine">
        <property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver" />
        <property name="additionalDialects">
            <set>
                <bean id="tilesDialect" class="org.thymeleaf.extras.tiles2.dialect.TilesDialect" />
            </set>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- tiles view resolver -->
    <bean id="tilesViewResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.thymeleaf.extras.tiles2.spring4.web.view.ThymeleafTilesView" />
        <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine" />
        <property name="characterEncoding" value="utf-8" />
        <property name="order" value="1" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**tiles.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.1//EN" "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_1.dtd">
<tiles-definitions>
    <!-- index -->
    <definition name="login" template="templates/login">
        <put-attribute name="head" value="fragments/head :: login_head" />
        <put-attribute name="content" value="content/login :: content" />
        <put-attribute name="privacy_policy" value="fragments/privacy_policy :: privacy_policy" />
        <put-attribute name="scripts" value="fragments/scripts :: loginScripts" />
    </definition>

    <!-- user -->
    <definition name="dashboard" template="templates/dashboard">
        <put-attribute name="head" value="fragments/head :: dashboard_head" />
        <put-attribute name="header" value="fragments/header :: header" />
        <put-attribute name="sidebar" value="fragments/sidebar :: sidebar" />
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="fragments/footer :: footer" />
        <put-attribute name="content" value="content/dashboard :: content" />
        <put-attribute name="privacy_policy" value="fragments/privacy_policy :: privacy_policy" />
        <put-attribute name="scripts" value="fragments/scripts :: dashboardScripts" />
    </definition>

    <definition name="profile" extends="dashboard">
        <put-attribute name="content" value="content/profile :: content" />
    </definition>

    <definition name="assets" extends="dashboard">
        <put-attribute name="content" value="content/assets :: content" />
    </definition>

</tiles-definitions>
```

**login.html (template)**

```
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:tiles="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <th:block tiles:include="head" th:remove="tag" />  
    <body>
        <!-- html -->
        <div id="page">
            <th:block tiles:include="content" th:remove="tag" />
            <th:block tiles:inlcude="privacy_policy" th:remove="tag" />
            <th:block tiles:include="scripts" th:remove="tag" />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**privacy_policy.html (new fragment)**

```
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
    xmlns:tiles="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <body>
    <th:block tiles:fragment="privacy_policy" th:remove="tag">
        <div class="jumbotron">ASDFASDFASDF</div>
        <h1>ASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDF</h1>
    </th:block>
    </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**

I can force an error from tiles by misspelling an attribute in my tiles definition.

```
...
    <definition name="login" template="templates/login">
                <put-attribute name="head" value="fragments/head :: login_MISSPELLED" />
...
```

But there is no error if I make a change to the new fragment

```
...
    <definition name="login" template="templates/login">
                <put-attribute name="privacy_policy" value="fragments/privacy_policy :: privacy_MISSPELLED" />
...
```

Comment: It definitely seems as if something is being cached, I have the cacheable false property set for the template resolver. I'm not sure what else could be happening here.

Comment: I have tried tomcat clean and clean work module directory. I also tried maven clean project. Both did not work. Am I missing something silly here?

Comment: I tried scrapping the entire project folder, repulling all code, and rebuilding, but still scratching my head on this one.

Answer (score 0):

It was a typo haha. Wow, that was a doozy. Here's the correction. It should be noted that no html validation, or even validation from my thymeleaf nature plugin, caught this as an issue. My own eyes just glossed right over it :\

**login.html (template)**

```
...
    <th:block tiles:include="privacy_policy" th:remove="tag" />
...
```